# Why does this code run differently in x64 release and debug?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

```
#include <iostream>

int binary_search(int (&arr)[6], const int &target) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = sizeof(arr) - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
      int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (arr[mid] == target) {
      return mid;
    } else if (arr[mid] > target) {
    high = mid - 1;
    } else if (arr[mid] < target) {
    low = mid + 1;
   }
  }
  return -1;
}

int main() {
   int arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};

   std::cout << binary_search(arr, 1) << std::endl;

   return 0;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCLVQ.png)

How can I change it to work correctly

AMD CPU R5 2600

vs2019 + LLVM 12.0.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM4WY.png)

Running results:

-1

F:\OpenGL\Source\x64\Debug\DGL.exe (进程 11860)已退出，代码为 0。
要在调试停止时自动关闭控制台，请启用“工具”->“选项”->“调试”->“调试停止时自动关闭控制台”。
按任意键关闭此窗口. . .

Normal result should be 0

Comment: The `int high = sizeof(arr) - 1;` ain't does what you think it should.

Comment: What does "work correctly" look like?  What is supposed to be conveyed by the image you posted?

Comment: @AdrianMole that is true! But this is a totally different computation from the `sizeof(arr)-1` on its own.

Comment: I know you know I know we know that knowing is half the battle

Comment: Why would the "normal result" be 1, when the value being searched for (1) is at index 0?

Comment: it is unclear why you use `sizeof` in the first place when in all other places in the code the size of the array is hardcoded as 6

Comment: @Adrian Mole  Its result is normal after entering this

Comment: @ScottHunter I did include *maybe* in my earlier (now deleted) comment. But I decided to post an answer, instead.

Comment: fwiw, getting different results in debug and release mode is an almost sure sign of undefined behavior

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` ≠ `std::size(arr)`

Answer (score 4):

The number of elements in an array is the size of the array *divided by the size of one of those elements*. So, in your code, to get the index of the last value, you need to include a division by `sizeof(int)`, like so:

```cpp
    int high = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)) - 1;
```

As it stands, your code is attempting to access "out-of-bounds" array elements and, as such exhibits undefined behaviour (UB). Such UB is unpredictable and will frequently manifest itself it different ways between different (i.e. Release and Debug) builds.

Furthermore, as you are passing a **fixed size** array as the first argument, you can just use that (known) size, instead of calculating it:

```cpp
    int high = 5;
```

Try adding an extra element to the array initializer in `main`, like so:

```cpp
    int arr[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 };
```

You will (or *should*) get an error message, like the following (generated by clang-cl):

```
error : no matching function for call to 'binary_search'
message : candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int [7]' to 'int (&)[6]' for 1st argument
```

Comment: int high = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)) - 1;

Comment: @Chris Always happy to help - that's what Stack Overflow is for! Feel free to [explore how SO works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).‎

Comment: @Chris If this answered your question, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: @Quimby -- not for a day or so.